(react－native)How to detect Touch event of list item(like web->hover)
I want to know how to detect the touch event of a list item. For example, I have a  FlatList  with  disableScroll={true} . When I perform a  TouchMove  on the list, how can I determine which item is being touched at the moment?https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help
I have tried to use  onTouchMove  in the item's props. However, when I start touching,  console.log(item)  logs the first item I touch, even if I move away from it.
the
Here is my code. Any help is appreciated.
 <View style={{marginVertical:'auto'}} >
        {sectionData.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <Pressable
            // logs the first item I touch, even if I move away from it.
              onHoverIn={()=>{
               console.log(item,'item')
              }}
              onTouchMove={()=>{

               console.log(item,'item')
              }}
             onPress={() =>
              onPressLetter({ realIndex: item?.realIndex as number, index })
             } >
      </Pressable>)
        })}
</View>

when touch move away from one Item(Pressable),console.log(item,'item') log the other Item

Well, I have solved this problem by calculating the height and the distance from the top of the page (pageY) of the list. I added a TouchMove event to the list and calculated the current touch index. However, I wonder if there is a prop, like the web hover event, that could make this process easier.
